# How can I run an applescript from my Mac with a shortcut (without using 3rd party apps)?

Tags: macos, mac, applescript

Hi I have an applescript that sends Outlook emails to Omnifocus - and it works when I run it manually, by clicking on and running the script.

Is there any way to do this with a shortcut without installing any 3rd party apps?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Make a new Service using Automator.
Add your AppleScript:

[image: alt]

Make a keyboard shortcut using System Preferences:

[image: alt]

Keyboard shortcuts will work across applications.

Comment: Just an aside I used the above method to allow myself to "Love" any track that is currently playing in itunes from anywhere on my mac using this apple script:
 
tell application "iTunes"
    set loved of current track to not loved of current track
end tell

Taken from: https://forum.keyboardmaestro.com/t/keyboard-shortcut-to-like-currently-playing-song-in-itunes-12-2/1488/3

Comment: How do I add the AppleScript as an action?

Comment: @theonlygusti : action as in ? .. the above method will create a shortcut and execute appleScript when we press those keys ..
please elaborate .

Comment: Your first step is "Add your AppleScript." I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Oh whoops, yes I just figured it out. I'm pretty noob at using apple scripts and automator. I just have to add the run apple script thing. Derp. Thank you for this answer.

Comment: By "Make a new Service", I guess you need to choose New > Quick Action ?

Comment: Awesome Sauce!  So glad this is here!

Answer (score -2):

To clarify @rahul_send89 answer:

- Open Automator
- Create 'Quick Action' (in order to create Service)
- Search for 'Run AppleScript' & double click to open the dialog
- Paste the script and save the Quick Action
- Open System Preferences > Keyboard > Services, under 'General' section set the shortcut key