# Keyboard shortcut to "Love" currently playing song in iTunes 12 on OSX

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, itunes, applescript

It seems as if apple has forgotten to build in a keyboard shortcut for "Loving" or "Hearting" the currently playing song in iTunes. This is unfortunate because often whilst I am working I would like to heart an unfamiliar song without context switching over to iTunes and loosing my focus. Is there any undocumented way of doing this? I know I can use automation similar to: [How can I run an applescript from my Mac with a shortcut (without using 3rd party apps)?](https://superuser.com/questions/815162/how-can-i-run-an-applescript-from-my-mac-with-a-shortcut-without-using-3rd-part) but it would be nice to be able to use something native to iTunes rather than an applescript such as:

```
tell application "iTunes"
set loved of current track to not loved of current track
end tell
```

https://forum.keyboardmaestro.com/t/keyboard-shortcut-to-like-currently-playing-song-in-itunes-12-2/1488/3

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find anything better than this solution, but I updated it to not "unlove" tracks that already marked as loved.

```
tell application "iTunes"
  if current track is not loved then
    set loved of current track to not loved of current track
  end if
end tell
```